# Show last updated date in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I want to display last updated date in umbraco 4.7

Say if i even make a small change in content from the admin panel, it has to pull the updated date so that i can show that in footer of the website dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Razor, or XSLT for your macros on the site?

Answer (score 5):

Every node has a property called `updateDate` which you can get in razor by using:

```
@Model.UpdateDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want it so that any update to any content item updates the "last updated" information in your footer.

I'd hook into the publish event ([this link](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-iapplicationeventhandler-to-register-events) should get you started),create a variable to store the date, and update it every time a node gets published, then read and output it in the code that generates your footer.